# How come new Audio("./mysound.mp3") works regardless of the path?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio

There is a javascript file `main.js` that has this code:

```
const mySound = new Audio('./sound/alert1.wav');

function playAlert() {
   mySound.currentTime = 0;
   mySound.play();
}
```

And I have the following structure of my project:

```
sound/
     alert1.wav
src/
   main.js
index.html
```

And the `index.html` includes the `src/main.js` as the script.
The page has a button that plays the sound by calling `playAlert()`.

I use VSCode [live server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) extension to run this.
And when I press the button, the sound plays just fine.
Now, when I change the path to:

```
const mySound = new Audio('../sound/alert1.wav');
```

or

```
const mySound = new Audio('../../../../../sound/alert1.wav');
```

It still plays!

I tried to search why, but honestly, I am not even sure what to search for.

Who can explain how does it work?

Comment: What do you expect "go up one level" to do from root?

Comment: @kaiido my question is basically how come no matter what path I specify it still works?

Comment: The path you are passing is not just any path though, it's just asking to "go up one level" many times. So in order to be able to explain to you correctly that from root (since your document.baseURI is probably "/ "), "going up one level" will do nothing, we need to know what other kind of behavior you were expecting, because explaining the obvious (to us) is an hard task.

Comment: @Kaiido well, you kind of answered my question, although indirectly. I am no frontend web developer. Have been always working on the backend side of things. I was just poking into some frontend project and was not familiar with things like document.baseURI etc. Once you mentioned it, everything suddenly started making sense.